# Regex Match Extended Common Log Format with Multiple Host

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex expression to match the extended common log format.  I have an expression to match most of the log entries, but it fails when multiple hosts are listed.

Here is my current expression:

```
([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[([^]]*)\] "([^"]*)" ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"
```

This successfully matches standard log entries.  For example:

```
24.58.227.240 - - [22/Sep/2011:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /rss/merchant/airsoftpost.com HTTP/1.1" 200 1880 "-" "Apple-PubSub/65"
```

However, some of the log entries contain multiple host IPs separated by commas:

```
10.64.233.43, 69.171.229.245 - - [22/Sep/2011:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /view/thesanctuary.co.uk HTTP/1.1" 206 7289 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
```

Could someone help me fix my expression to match any number of hosts for a given log item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your regex, you can change:

```
([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[([^]]*)\] "([^"]*)" ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"
```

To

```
([^-]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[([^]]*)\] "([^"]*)" ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"
   ^--- here, match until first dash
```

The idea is to change only the first group:

```
([^ ]*)   ---> matches until the first space (change this)
([^-]*)   ---> matches until the first hyphen
```

Answer (score 1):

As an option, try this regex pattern:

`([\d.\s,]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[([^]]*)\] "([^"]*)" ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"`

The first capturing group will now capture all digits, periods, (white)spaces, any number of repetitions.

See [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR1sS1/1).